# What gets put into Github's release notification email?

Tags: email, github, notifications

What is it that Github includes, from the source code or release process, in the email notification for a new release?

This is all I'm seeing:

```
—
View it on GitHub.
```

Trying to figure out how to get release notes/changes into the email, automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of tools that can be used to generate a CHANGELOG.md - but I was looking for the built-in-to-Github solution.  All I could really find was this:

https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software

It appears to just use commits since previous tag/release and issues related.  It doesn't look like you can provide your own.

I'm also running into an issue associated with creating a tag from a branch, rather than the 'default' - master.